# Creating links in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Dilemma, I am creating hundreds of reports and these reports require users to input comments. The comments are collected in one main file. This file use's link's to the hundreds of files that have been created to get the comments. The problem arises when attempting to update the links in the main file before the few hundred or so files are published.

Is it possible to input a link that does not exist yet and not get #REF or a prompt to select a link. Actually the #REF is fine I just want to get rid of the prompt to select a valid link.

Do you think I can turn off the warnings with VBA and still have the Find and Replace work. Essentially all I am doing is replacing the date. I have been think about this for to long. if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Thank you, Jim

Comment: You can disable alerts in the `Workbook_Open()` event with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` but I would not recommend it: it is an Application-level setting which will apply to all other workbooks and the entire Excel Application.  There may be another way to disable them for this file only but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Set your cell as a text field (start the line with ' ) and then you can do a find and replace later.  Typically when I want to do something like that I will have the cell like so:

'replacethis content

Where content is my formula and the 'replacethis is a place holder to find and replace later.